# Group by with condition and get number of items grouped XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am working with the following JSON structure, I have two Items arrays that might contain the same objects. I need to only get distinct items (based on the `Id`) where the OrderId equals a specific value.

```
[
   {
           "Items":[
             {
                "Id":"12",
                "OrderId":"570",
                "ProductId":"212"
                "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
                "Amount":{
                   "Value":25.0,
                   "Net":25.0,
                   "Tax":0.0
                }
             },
                      {
                "Id":"123",
                "OrderId":"570",
                "ProductId":"212"
                "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
                "Amount":{
                   "Value":25.0,
                   "Net":25.0,
                   "Tax":0.0
                }
             },
                      {
                "Id":"1234",
                "OrderId":"570",
                "ProductId":"232"
                "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
                "Amount":{
                   "Value":25.0,
                   "Net":25.0,
                   "Tax":0.0
                }
             }
          ]
   },
   {

          "Items":[
             {
                "Id":"12",
                "OrderId":"570",
                "ProductId":"212"
                "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
                "Amount":{
                   "Value":25.0,
                   "Net":25.0,
                   "Tax":0.0
                }
             },
                      {
                "Id":"123",
                "OrderId":"570",
                "ProductId":"212"
                "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
                "Amount":{
                   "Value":25.0,
                   "Net":25.0,
                   "Tax":0.0
                }
             },
                      {
                "Id":"1234",
                "OrderId":"570",
                "ProductId":"232"
                "Type":"ServiceRevenue",
                "Amount":{
                   "Value":25.0,
                   "Net":25.0,
                   "Tax":0.0
                }
             }
          ]
   }
]
```

I want to group based on the `ProductId`, and check how many occurrences of that `ProductId` are. From the example I provided, I should have two occurrences of ProductId = 212 and 1 of 232.

I am trying the following XSLT that doesn't seem to work.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//fn:array[@key= 'Items']/fn:map[*[@key = 'OrderId'][.= $OrderId ]]" group-by="*[@key = 'Id'] ">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="current()" group-by="*[@key = 'ProductId'] ">
      string key="units">
         <xsl:value-of select="count(current-grouping-key())" />
      </string>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: I haven't tried to understand the full detail, but in the inner xsl:for-each-group, shouldn't `select="current()"` be `select="current-group()"`?

Comment: Consider to show the XML you are working with instead of the JSON if the XSLT you show works against the XML. And it helps if you show minimal but complete samples to demonstrate the issue. JSON "mess" where each `"ProductId":"212"` misses a trailing comma is hard to work with and if you use variables like `$OrderId` we can only understand the sample and the wanted result if you show how/where you bind a variable value.